# How to place a Parabola/Distribution on top of a node in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, edge

I'm trying right now to place a distribution (preferably a Gaussian curve) on top of a node within TikzPicture. The distribution should ideally be slightly offset vertically from the node, although that is not essential. The code I am trying to extend is as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=2.5cm, scale=1.5]
\tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
\tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
\tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
\tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
\tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

% Draw the input layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,4}
% This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
    \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

% Draw the hidden layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5}
    \path[yshift=0.5cm]
        node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (2.5cm,-\y cm) {};

% Draw the output layer node
\node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-3] (O) {};

% Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
% hidden layer.
\foreach \source in {1,...,4}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
        \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

% Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
\foreach \source in {1,...,5}
    \path (H-\source) edge (O);

% Annotate the layers
\node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
\node[annot,above of=I-1, node distance=1cm] {Input layer};
\node[annot,above of=O] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Resulting in

[image: 1-layer Neural Network]

What I would ideally have is something similar to the following:

[image: Desired image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can embed it in the `neuron` style with the `path picture` key:

```
neuron/.style={
    circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt,
    path picture={
        \draw[red,thick,-] plot[domain=-0.3:0.3,samples=11,smooth] ({\x},{0.05*g(\x)});
    },
},
```

I've defined the Gaussian as

```
\tikzset{
    declare function={
        sig = 0.1;
        mu = 0;
        g(\x) = 1/(sig*sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-1/2 * ((\x-mu)/sig)^2);
    }
}
```

This results in:

[image]

Note that I also changed your `\tikzstyle` commands, because it is considered deprecated.
Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    declare function={
        sig = 0.1;
        mu = 0;
        g(\x) = 1/(sig*sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-1/2 * ((\x-mu)/sig)^2);
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    shorten >=1pt,
    ->,
    draw=black!50,
    node distance=2.5cm,
    scale=1.5,
    every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
    neuron/.style={
        circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt,
        path picture={
            \draw[red,thick,-] plot[domain=-0.3:0.3,samples=11,smooth] ({\x},{0.05*g(\x)});
        },
    },
    input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50},
    output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
    hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=blue!50},
    annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered},
]

% Draw the input layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,4}
% This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
    \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

% Draw the hidden layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5}
    \path[yshift=0.5cm]
        node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (2.5cm,-\y cm) {};

% Draw the output layer node
\node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-3] (O) {};

% Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
% hidden layer.
\foreach \source in {1,...,4}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
        \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

% Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
\foreach \source in {1,...,5}
    \path (H-\source) edge (O);

% Annotate the layers
\node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
\node[annot,above of=I-1, node distance=1cm] {Input layer};
\node[annot,above of=O] {Output layer};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty bad code, but it works (node style – only works when using scalebox with scale factor unqeual to 0 or 1 and some othre bugs):

```
\documentclass[border=.5cm,tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    neuron/.style={
        append after command={
            \pgfextra{
                \node[thick,draw=blue!70,fill=blue!20,circle,inner sep=1cm] (a) at (\tikzlastnode) {};
                \draw[thick,red] (a.west) parabola ([xshift=1cm,yshift=.5cm]a.west) to[bend left=50] ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=.5cm]a.east);
                \draw[thick,red] (a.east) parabola ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=.5cm]a.east);
            }
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \scalebox{.5}[.5]{\node[neuron] at (0,0) {};}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It seems that this works in isolation, however, it causes an error when integrated into the code snippet I pasted in the original question. Do you know this is?