# How to draw a function on a section of a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, function

I want to draw the blue "Gaussian" (approximated using sinc) on the black line going through the bullet point exactly like how it rests on the actual axis with its center above the bullet point and it not touching the black line. The scale should also be appropriate. How may I go about doing that?

[image: Plots]

Here is the code:

```
\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
        \pgfmathdeclarefunction{sinc}{1}{%
        \pgfmathparse{abs(#1)<0.01 ? int(1) : int(0)}%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0 \pgfmathparse{1}\else\pgfmathparse{sin(#1 r)/#1}\fi%
        }
        
        \def\x{1} % replace 1 with desired value here
        \draw[->] (-1.2,0) -- (2.6,0) node[right] {$\Psi_1$};
        \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,2.6) node[above left] {$\Psi_2$};

        \draw[-] (1.1,1.5) -- (1.9,1.5);

        \foreach \Point in { (1.5,1.5)}{
        \node at \Point {\textbullet};}
        
        \draw[blue,domain=-1.3:1.3,samples=202,smooth] plot (\x,{2*sinc(2.1*\x)});

        \node (A) at (1.99, 1.29) {\footnotesize$S_m$};

         \foreach \Point in { (1.66,1.35), (1.56,1.25),(1.45,1.19),(1.62,1.41),(1.76,1.35),(1.76,1.65),(1.26,1.25),(1.4,1.42),(1.46,1.85),(1.56,1.6),(1.46,1.75),(1.32,1.3),(1.39,1.55),(1.28,1.47),(1.36,1.4),(1.39,1.65),(1.22,1.61) }{
        \node at \Point {\tiny $\ast$};} 
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Possibly useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446948/how-to-place-a-parabola-distribution-on-top-of-a-node-in-tikz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @John Kormylo for linking to another question that was quite helpful for me in figuring it out.

Here is the working code:

```
\begin{center}
        \tikzstyle{hidden}=[circle,fill=white!25,minimum size=50pt,inner sep=0pt, path picture={
            \draw[blue,thick,-] plot[domain=-0.4:0.4,samples=15,smooth] ({\x},{0.3*g(\x)});
        },]
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.6]
        \pgfmathdeclarefunction{sinc}{1}{%
        \pgfmathparse{abs(#1)<0.01 ? int(1) : int(0)}%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0 \pgfmathparse{1}\else\pgfmathparse{sin(#1 r)/#1}\fi%
        }
        
        \def\x{1} % replace 1 with desired value here
        \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (2.6,0) node[right] {$\Psi_1$};
        \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,2.6) node[above left] {$\Psi_2$};
        
        \node (h)[hidden] at (1.5, 1.5){};
        
        \foreach \Point in { (1.5,1.5)}{
        \node at \Point {\textbullet};}
        
        \node (A) at (1.99, 1.29) {\footnotesize$S_m$};

         \foreach \Point in { (1.66,1.35), (1.56,1.25),(1.45,1.19),(1.62,1.41),(1.76,1.35),(1.76,1.65),(1.26,1.25),(1.4,1.42),(1.46,1.85),(1.56,1.6),(1.49,1.75),(1.32,1.3),(1.39,1.55),(1.28,1.47),(1.36,1.4),(1.39,1.65),(1.22,1.61) }{
        \node at \Point {\tiny $\ast$};} 
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

The definition of the Gaussian can be found in the linked question!